# Difference between cause of and cause for

Tags: prepositions

Could someone please tell me whether to use **of** or **for** in the sentence given below:-

Inactivity is the greatest cause **of/for** overweight.

Please also explain the logic used to make the distinction.

Comment: This is [General Reference](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/cause) on ELU. English Language Learners may be able to explain the different prepositions.

Comment: My comment to the original ELU question wasn't transferred across to ELL, so here is is again: Note that ***overweight*** is an *adjective*, so it's incorrect here (***obesity*** is a suitable *noun* replacement). Idiomatically, *"Inactivity is the greatest cause **of** obesity"* is better (grammatically, I mean - I'm sure overeating is a far more significant factor if we're talking factually).

Comment: Per The Free Dictionary, overweight is both an adjective and a noun.

Answer (score 3):

Inactivity is a cause for concern because it is the greatest cause of obesity.

Cause for X = reason to have X  (reason to be concerned)

Cause of X =  that which produces X  (factor that creates obesity)